# Use pandas.resample to take last value of each month for stock data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with stock data for multiple companies that looks like this:

```
dict = {'company': {201156: 18673,
  201157: 18673,
  201158: 18673,
  201159: 18673,
  201160: 18673,
  201161: 18673,
  201162: 18673,
  201162: 18673},
 'priceClose': {201156: 18.1,
  201157: 17.85,
  201158: 17.97,
  201159: 18.29,
  201160: 18.74,
  201161: 18.5,
  201162: 18.35,
  201162: 18.54},
 'pricingDate': {201156: Timestamp('2020-09-21 00:00:00'),
  201157: Timestamp('2020-09-22 00:00:00'),
  201158: Timestamp('2020-09-23 00:00:00'),
  201159: Timestamp('2020-09-24 00:00:00'),
  201160: Timestamp('2020-09-25 00:00:00'),
  201161: Timestamp('2020-09-28 00:00:00'),
  201162: Timestamp('2020-09-29 00:00:00'),
  201162: Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00')},
 'industryName': {201156: 'Energy',
  201157: 'Energy',
  201158: 'Energy',
  201159: 'Energy',
  201160: 'Energy',
  201161: 'Energy',
  201162: 'Energy',
  201162: 'Energy'},
 'indexCode': {201156: 'sp500',
  201157: 'sp500',
  201158: 'sp500',
  201159: 'sp500',
  201160: 'sp500',
  201161: 'sp500',
  201162: 'sp500',
  201162: 'sp500'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

I want to basically generate a df with all the columns in the current df, but the `priceClose` should be the month end value value. So for the example shown, the `priceClose` for company `18673` should be `18.54` as it's the last value for that month.

I tried the following code using `pd.resample` but it doesn't seem to work with a multiindex.

```
df.set_index(['pricingDate','company','industryName','indexCode'])['priceClose'].resample('M').ffill()
```

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the dates are sorted, use `groupby.transform`:

```
g = pd.to_datetime(df['pricingDate']).dt.to_period('M')

df['priceClose'] = df.groupby(g)['priceClose'].transform('last')
```

Output:

```
        company  priceClose pricingDate industryName indexCode
201156    18673       18.54  2020-09-21       Energy     sp500
201157    18673       18.54  2020-09-22       Energy     sp500
201158    18673       18.54  2020-09-23       Energy     sp500
201159    18673       18.54  2020-09-24       Energy     sp500
201160    18673       18.54  2020-09-25       Energy     sp500
201161    18673       18.54  2020-09-28       Energy     sp500
201162    18673       18.54  2020-09-30       Energy     sp500
```

If the dates are not in order, you can `sort_values`:

```
g = pd.to_datetime(df['pricingDate']).dt.to_period('M')

df['priceClose'] = df.sort_values(by='priceClose').groupby(g)['priceClose'].transform('last')
```

Or without sorting, with `idxmax` and a double `map`:

```
g = pd.to_datetime(df['pricingDate']).dt.to_period('M')

s = df['priceClose'].groupby(g).idxmax()

df['priceClose'] = g.map(s.map(df['priceClose']))
```

Example on the shuffled input:

```
        company  priceClose pricingDate industryName indexCode
201158    18673       18.74  2020-09-23       Energy     sp500
201161    18673       18.74  2020-09-28       Energy     sp500
201156    18673       18.74  2020-09-21       Energy     sp500
201162    18673       18.74  2020-09-30       Energy     sp500
201160    18673       18.74  2020-09-25       Energy     sp500
201157    18673       18.74  2020-09-22       Energy     sp500
201159    18673       18.74  2020-09-24       Energy     sp500
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified your example set slightly to include two months. Grouping by month and year, finding the last value in a separate column (lastClose), and filling upwards solves the problem.

```py
df.assign(lastPrice = df.groupby([df.pricingDate.dt.month, df.pricingDate.dt.year])
          .tail(1).priceClose).bfill()
```

Output:

```py
        company priceClose  pricingDate industryName    indexCode   month   year    lastClose
0   18673   18.1    2020-09-21  Energy  sp500   9   2020    18.29
1   18673   17.85   2020-09-22  Energy  sp500   9   2020    18.29
2   18673   17.97   2020-09-23  Energy  sp500   9   2020    18.29
3   18673   18.29   2020-09-24  Energy  sp500   9   2020    18.29
4   18673   18.74   2020-10-25  Energy  sp500   10  2020    18.54
5   18673   18.5    2020-10-28  Energy  sp500   10  2020    18.54
6   18673   18.54   2020-10-30  Energy  sp500   10  2020    18.54
```